# Swift - UICollectionView reloadItems takes too long

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, nsindexpath

I want to reload only single cell after user select the contact `(method didSelect contact)`. If the number of item in cell getting bigger, the process is getting slower. I also try to implement in `DispatchQueue.main.async { code }` and it still take some time to load.

**cellForItemAt and noOfItemInSection (AddCell) - Total cell 4**

```
var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   indexPaths.append(indexPath)

   if indexPath.item == 1 {
        let addCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellId, for: indexPath) as! AddCell
        addCell.btnAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOpenContact), for: .touchUpInside)
        addCell.invitees = invitees
        return addCell
    }
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
```

**cellForItemAt and noOfItemInSection (SubAddCell)**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: subAddId, for: indexPath) as! SubAddCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.invitee = invitees[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return invitees.count
    }
```

**didSelect (ContactPicker)**

```
func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact) {
        let invitee = Invitee()
        invitee.name = contact.givenName

        if contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactPhoneNumbersKey) {
            for phoneNumber: CNLabeledValue in contact.phoneNumbers {
                let a = phoneNumber.value
                print("\(a.stringValue)")
                invitee.phoneNo = a.stringValue
            }
        }
        self.invitees.append(invitee)

        for index in self.indexPaths {
            if index == [0, 0] {
                print(index)
                self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [index])
            }
        }
    }
```

I have obtain the value of `indexPaths` at `cellForItemAt` method. If the invitee contains 5 items, the `print(index)` will print 19 values. I dont know why. Below is the image.

[image]

Design of the UI

[image]

How to optimize the reloadItems?

Any help is really appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: can you describe the rest of your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method? you only show that you handle the cell at index 1... whereas you clearly have 19 cells being used. What's the rest of the method?

Comment: @murphguy, it was only 4 cell. For that particular cell, have a `UICollectionView` inside it. I have update the questions.

Comment: Well therein lies your challenge. Collapsable cell animation/handling is rather heavy. So it depends on : do you use autolayout within the cell or not? is the content of the cell dynamic? are you loading images asyncronously via a seperate thread? those three questions should answer your question as to why your app is laggy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have this `indexPaths.append(indexPath)` in `cellForItemAt` so that why the indexPaths can increase after reload data. You might use NSSet instead of NSArray to make sure your objects are unique.

And with this: `cell.invitee = invitees[indexPath.item]`, did you implement didSet for `invitee`?
If you did, I think need to prepare data in background queue first. E.g.

```
DispatchQueue(label: "queue").async {
  let image = <# process image here #>
  let name = <# process name here #>
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.imageView.image = image
    self.label.text = name
  }
}
```

Hope my tips could help you!

Comment: I did implement didSet for `invitee`. NSSet need to be set as IndexPath ?
I didnt get you.

Comment: -I guess your `didSet` take a lot of time to process data to fill to your UI elements.
- And NSSet make sure your indexPaths are not duplicated!

Answer (score 0):

`Collectionviews` are the most powerful UI tool of iOS, but if done wrong, or if misused (which happens, don't worry), they can be worse for your UX. . To view how this stuff is affected read up on XCode Tools and how to use them to debug your UI performance.

Important note to consider:

frame-by-frame operations (ie, loading your collectionviewcell, expanded, or unexpanded) should take no more than 17 ms to execute for smooth scrolling.

[UICollectionView performance - _updateVisibleCellsNow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336772/uicollectionview-performance-updatevisiblecellsnow)

So you need to make your cells as simple and efficient as possible. That's the best place to start, especially if your expandable cells themselves contain complex subviews like `collectionviews`.