# Improve performance of UIVisualEffect (blur) applied to UIImageView inside cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm using a UIVisualEffect that applies a blur effect to a UIImageView inside a custom cell for a UICollectionView. This is used as the background of the cell which takes up the whole screen.

```
    UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
    blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
    self.blurEffect = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    self.blurEffect.frame = self.blurBackground.bounds;

[self.blurBackground addSubview:self.blurEffect];
```

When I scroll, the frame rate drops a bit until the cell movement stops.

I tried:

```
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

but this just makes things worse (I understood why on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521959/uiview-self-layer-shouldrasterize-yes-and-performance-issues)).

I am using dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier.

From what I understand, the blur effect is getting re-calculated all the time, so perhaps I can save the blurred image instead of re-rendering it on every frame? Any idea how to do this?

Or any other ideas on how to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

implement the UIScrollViewDelegate, when -[
scrollViewWillBeginDragging:] remove the blur, and 
-[scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:] add the blur view again. This may be fine for the scroll animation.

Comment: But I need the blur view when scrolling, otherwise it will look bad when the blur gets removed or added. I will upload a screenshot, perhaps it will make things clearer.

Comment: Or update the blur view to the background view, just merge two view layer to one , so when scroll just use the merged view to show.  No use this render method like your that one.