# Draw border and keep above all subviews in view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been thinking about this one for a while. Basically, the code below draws a border on a `UIView`, but, if I add another `UIView` as a subview to that `UIView` - it'll appear above the border.

**Like this:**

[image]

How do I *(as cleanly as possible)*, keep the border above all subviews?

**Like this:**

[image]

This is what I have so far. But, like stated above, it doesn't keep the border above all its subviews.

```
    CGPathRef CGPathRect = CGPathCreateWithRect(rect, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGPathRef border = CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath(rect.CGPath, NULL, 5.0f, kCGLineCapButt, kCGLineJoinMiter, 0);
    CGContextAddPath(context, border);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, someCGColor);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
    CGPathRelease(border);
```

I could create a separate `UIView` for the border itself, and just insert subviews below that `UIView`, but that feels rather hackish. If there's a better way - I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use view.layer.borderWidth and view.layer.borderColor ?

Comment: This is what i was about to ask, why use that expensive core graphics stuff, when u have two properties of view.layer who do exactly that.

Comment: The reason is that `layer.border` doesn't conform to views that are of circular shape. I.e, round the corners via `UIBezierPath` and you'll see what I'm talking about. `layer.border` will be a rectangle.

Comment: @Cookies view.layer.cornerRadius for rounded corners. So, what more you need?

Comment: cornerRadius is very expensive. Therefore, I'm using `UIBezierPath`

Comment: @Cookies  view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
view.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale; for performance... what more you need? :)

Comment: What are those properties supposed to do? @Sneak

Comment: @Cookies Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521959/uiview-self-layer-shouldrasterize-yes-and-performance-issues

Comment: @Sneak Read: http://asyncdisplaykit.org/docs/corner-rounding.html

Comment: @Cookies It's all basically up to use-case and what your app is doing. Did you even try it before linking that? I have a ** MASSIVE ** social feed page made in a UITableView where I have images with rounded corners, and I am scrolling at maximum FPS on an old 4s. So, it's all from case to case .. However, adding an UIView on top of another UIView is not a hacky way at all. I use UIViews for custom borders here and there. Also, you should look into https://coderwall.com/p/6gsc8g/applying-rounded-corners-to-a-view-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1):

I would say use:

```
 view.clipToBounds       = YES;
 view.layer.borderColor  = [UIColor redColor];
 view.layer.borderWidth  = 2;
 view.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
```

All subviews are clipped and u can keep ur border :).

Comment: add cornerRadius to your answer

Comment: I added it for the sake of community but the OP wanted border only. :)

Comment: Ah you havnt been following our conversation in the comment section :)